# Correct input-output relationship for binary logistic regression

Tags: logistic, deep-learning

In section **6.2.2.2 Sigmoid Units for Bernoulli Output Distributions** of the [Deep Learning](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/mlp.html#pf11) book, the author gave a logistic regression model for binary classification $P(y)=\sigma(z)$ where $\sigma$ is the logistic sigmoid function and $z$ is a linear/affine transformation of input $x$. The author then said that:

> Saturation thus occurs only when the model already has the right
>   answer—when $y=1$ and $z$ is very positive, or $y=0$ and $z$ is
>   very negative.

I'm just wondering why this is the correct input-output relationship to be learned.